# Removing the default link from image Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building a website in WordPress and I am facing an issue with gallery images. I used the plugin FooGallery to show the Grid Images and I also added the onclick to the FooBox to show the larger image.

But the problem is when I click on the image it is showing in two image box. first one is maybe WordPress default and second is the FooBox.

Link for the gallery: http://www.3rdeyeholographic.com/void/

Open this link and click on any one image and see what happen. It will show two image box but I want only one which is good in UI.

Comment: Did you used magnific popup?

Comment: it seems you are using two plugins, please check and remove one popup plugin

Comment: no, I didn't use anything. checkout this link: http://www.3rdeyeholographic.com/2d-3d-holograms/

In this link, I use the visual composer gallery for the 1st 4 images and FooGallery for the rest. I think the link for the first 4 images are the default link that is also occurring in the FooGallery.

Comment: @Darshkhakhkhar you're right, the Magnific popup is enabled in theme plugin. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing trx addons plugin to remove one of the popup.

Comment: Can you provide more information, please? Why is this the solution?

Comment: The popup you want to remove seems to come from that plugin as I inspect your site. Maybe there's an option to deactivate that feature on the plugin. If so, you might not need to deactivate the plugin. If you're not willing to remove the plugin, you can use CSS to hide that popup. But not so convenient solution.

Comment: http://www.3rdeyeholographic.com/

check the website after removing the trx addon

Comment: Solved, Magnific popup is enabled in the trx addon plugin,, it solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Keep exploring :)